# How to restore files accidentally removed from shared google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

I have accidentally clicked on remove instead of download in a shared file in Gdrive.

I had edit access of the file.

Few things need to know about this,

1. Does the file will be still available for the other shared peoples??. Wanted to make sure file not removed permanently.
2. If the file is not permanently removed. How could i re-add the file in my view back.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Does this google help page work for you?

https://support.google.com/a/answer/7376096?hl=en

It looks like Google has a built-in system to recover lost files.

If you aren't the owner or the original creator of the file, there is also a good chance they are still on others' shared folder. ([Google Forumn](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/15231077?hl=en))